# Is it some way to change the main or we can say oncreate activity on the basis of some condition?

Tags: android

I want to to start the oncreate activity on the basis of condition like what I want to do is to verify the IMEI number of mobile if it matches application has to open login screen otherwise signup screen.
I want signup some thing like whatsapp like we see the signup screen once.
I am doing on the basis of IMEI is it good way??? if not than please suggest me some thing.
And what can i do for the activity changing.

Here is some code

```
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TelephonyManager mngr =(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if(mngr.getDeviceId().equals(mngr.getDeviceId())){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registeration);        
    }else
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
}
```

I know this is some thing illogical but how can i do so.

Comment: **"I am doing on the basis of IMEI is it good way???"** : Only if you want to support devices with phone support and ignore anything which doesn't. A tablet without phone capability doesn't have an IMEI number for example.

Comment: @Squonk  Is it some other way to cater it other than IMEI what are the basis of Whatsapp

Comment: I have no idea about Whatsapp as I've never used it. You might want to look at OAuth as a possibility (Google for it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't, under any circumstance, call lifecycle methods of `Activities`; it the framework's duty to call them when it is the correct time for them to be called.

There are many ways you could accomplish the sign up screen feature. One that comes to mind is to use `Fragments` and an `Activity` to manage them. If the user is logged in, you display the hypothetical `LoggedInFragment`. Otherwise, you display the `SignUpFragment`.

Comment: No, I will not share some code. I suggest you read the Android guide on [`Fragments`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this "alternate `setContentView()`" approach, but then you would need to have the logic for both tasks in the same class, which is kind of kludgy.

Possible alternatives:

- Use Fragments (one for each task) and add either one in `onCreate()` depending on the condition.
- Call another Activity (via `startActivity()` in `onCreate()`) for the alternate task.

Comment: which one is better fragment or startActivity like I have told the circumstances in which I want to use it, I don't even want to show the main activity if IMEI matches like whatsapp.

Comment: In startActivity() approach on pressing back button i will get the main screen which I don't realy want.I know it is not a big deal we can cater it but some thing more efficient.

Comment: You can just call finish() straight after startActivity() if you want, which would close it.

Comment: @WaseemFarooqui I assumed you wanted to return to the "default" task after completing the secondary one. In any case you can call finish() as suggested.